# Entity Framework returns ICollection<> with no values

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have 2 entities in a Many-To-Many relationship and I'd like to add a student to a class, but after I receive the class object from a query it shows that the property is empty. I've seen lots of similar problems but no answer really helped me in this case.

Here are my classes:

Student Entity

```
class Student
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Surname { get; set; }

    public Student()
    {
        Classes = new HashSet<Class>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes { get; set; }
}
```

Class Entity

```
class Class
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string ClassName { get; set; }

    public Class()
    {
        Students = new HashSet<Student>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

Context

```
class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DatabaseContext>(new Initializer());
    }
}
```

Initializer

```
class Initializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<DatabaseContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {
        Student student1 = new Student { Id = 1, Name = "Name", Surname = "Surname" };

        Class class1 = new Class { Id = 1, ClassName = "Math"};
        class1.Students.Add(student1); // The Count of the collection is 1

        context.Students.Add(student1);
        context.Classes.Add(class1);

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Now when I try and receive the object through a method, the Count of the collection is 0

```
public static Class GetClass(int classId)
    {
        using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            Class receivedClass = context.Classes.Find(classId); // The collection is empty, the ClassName is there, though

            return receivedClass;
        }
    }
```

I'd like to know how can I add an object to a Collection of another object and then be able to also retrieve the object with the contents in the Collection

Comment: You need a `SavaChanges()` in Initializer class.

Comment: I've tried that, but the results are the same

Comment: What EF version you are using.

Comment: I am using the 6.2.0 EF version

Comment: I think this `class1.Students.Add(student1);` doesn't needed because you are adding students with `context.Students.Add(student1);`. And you need to ad the `SaveChanges` after.

Comment: You are loading classes, not students. You need to either trigger lazy loading (like with `receivedClass.Students`) or use `Classes.Include(x => x.Students).SingleAsync(x => x.ClassId == classId);`

Comment: With `class1.Students.Add(student1);` I try to add the student to the class1's Collection of students

Comment: @Llazar Forget about it. The problem is not, at all, related to *saving* the data. The problem is how the OP is *loading* the data

Comment: Yeah I see. Supposing there is other files in project I thought that's the problem.

Comment: @Camilo Terevinto I have used the second option that you've given and it worked, thank you

Comment: Isn't Lazy loading on by default on EF? Or did they change that since I became a Scala dev?

Comment: Yes, I think it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [.Include()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include(v=vs.103).aspx). There are a couple different strategies for [loading related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

```
using (var context = new DatabaseContext())
{
    // Load all students and related classes
    var classes1 = context.Classes
                    .Include(s => s.Students)
                    .ToList();

    // Load one student and its related classes
    var classt1 = context.Classes
                   .Where(s => s.Name == "someClassName")
                   .Include(s => s.Students)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

    // Load all students and related classes  
    // using a string to specify the relationship
    var classes2 = context.Classes
                    .Include("Students")
                    .ToList();

    // Load one student and its related classes  
    // using a string to specify the relationship
    var class2 = context.Classes
                   .Where(s => s.Name == "someName")
                   .Include("Students")
                   .FirstOrDefault();
}
```